# NGINX - Wordpress infinite redirect loop

Tags: wordpress, nginx, dns, redirect-loop

I'm new to using nginx. Up until now I was using as an hosting engine APACHE2, and because of it I have an issue with my website migration

here is my VHOST config file:

```
server {
        root /var/www/html/domain_com/web/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

        error_log /var/www/html/domain_com/log/error.log;
        access_log /var/www/html/domain_com/log/nginx-access.log;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

        location ~* \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                include         fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;

                fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
                fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
                fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        }

        include /var/www/html/domain_com/web/nginx.conf; 

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = www.domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

with config like this when I call the website it returns me error "too many redirects", but if I will add `listen 80;` at the top of first server block everything works just fine, but certbot while adding certs for next domain displays warning about that server name already exists and information that the warning was ignored.

what can i do, to solve this problem? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri permanent;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        root /var/www/html/domain_com/web/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

        error_log /var/www/html/domain_com/log/error.log;
        access_log /var/www/html/domain_com/log/nginx-access.log;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

        location ~* \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                include         fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;

                fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
                fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
                fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        }

    include /var/www/html/domain_com/web/nginx.conf; 


    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Comment: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "if($scheme" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/domain_com:33

Comment: should i define something in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file ?

Comment: Hey update the config. Which version on nginx you are using?

Comment: nginx version: nginx/1.14.0

Comment: after config update, have same error as before ("too many redirects")

Comment: additionally, wp-admin returns 403 forbidden page